# Python RSA library?

Tags: python, rsa, cryptography

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
private = RSA.generate(1024, os.urandom)
```

Now how do I export or import keys? Everything is there except these 2 functions!

```
private.exportKey()
private.publickey.exportKey()
```

Preferably in --armor format :)

Any ideas?

---

Thanks all. Turned out that Ubuntu installs an old version of PyCrypto and I had to fetch 2.3 from their website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using PyCryto, then I see that PyCryto 2.2 has that functionality. Otherwise you will find the patch [here useful](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pycrypto/+bug/500820).

Answer (score 0):

Crypto.PublicKey's exportKey is within module rsa, under _RSAobj class. You can look at the documentation [here](http://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/apidoc/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA._RSAobj-class.html#exportKey). You can export the public or private key with 'DER' (PKCS#1) or 'PEM' (RFC1421) format.